# Ambiguous redirect error : Remote execution of a command

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to execute a command remotely. The command works fine on local server. However when run remotely, it complains about ambiguous redirection. Could you please help me fix the same.

The command runs fine on local as follows:

```
    echo '{"service": {"name": "$service", "port":443, "check":{"script":"curl '"$NODE_IP:443"' >/dev/null 2>&1","interval":"10s"}}}' | tee /etc/module/test.json
```

I store the above command in a variable

```
    command="echo '{"service": {"name": "$service", "port":443, "check":{"script":"curl '"$NODE_IP:443"' >/dev/null 2>&1","interval":"10s"}}}' | tee /etc/module/test.json"
```

And then execute it:

```
    remoteExecute $remotehost $command
```

- remoteExecute is a function which we have written.

Comment: Are you sure it is working in local server?

Comment: echo '{"service": {"name": "$service", "port":443, "check":{"script":"curl \'"$NODE_IP:443"\' >/dev/null 2>&1","interval":"10s"}}}' | tee /etc/module/test.json

Comment: Yes it does Sridharan.

Comment: Try the command which I just posted now!

Comment: The one you have posted does not work on local node.

Comment: what type of shell are using to execute the remote command ?

Comment: @Abis  : I am using bash.

Comment: is the remote machine a unix or linux system?

Comment: Both local & remote are Linux instances.

Comment: Obligatory reading: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @Chepner, Thanks for the information

Answer (score 0):

The quoting has some problem.

```
command="echo '{"service": {"name": "$service", "port":443, "check":{"script":"curl '"$NODE_IP:443"' >/dev/null 2>&1","interval":"10s"}}}' | tee /etc/module/test.json"
```

please try below one

```
command='echo '\''{"service": {"name": "$service", "port":443, "check":{"script":"curl '\''"$NODE_IP:443"'\'' >/dev/null 2>&1","interval":"10s"}}}'\'' | tee /etc/module/test.json'
```

Putting this in a script and echoing it shows that the command variable holds what you wanted.

```
#!/bin/bash
command='echo '\''{"service": {"name": "$service", "port":443, "check":{"script":"curl '\''"$NODE_IP:443"'\'' >/dev/null 2>&1","interval":"10s"}}}'\'' | tee /etc/module/test.json'
echo "$command"

linux:~/Tst> ./test.sh 
echo '{"service": {"name": "$service", "port":443, "check":{"script":"curl '"$NODE_IP:443"' >/dev/null 2>&1","interval":"10s"}}}' | tee /etc/module/test.json
```

Comment: What is the command that you want to be executed in the remote node ?

Comment: Thanks Abis. It runs fine locally but when the same command I execute remotely it fails.

Comment: I want to run the full command remotely starting from echo. The output of command echo is what I want to 'tee' to a file.

Comment: bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: you could show us the implementation of   `remoteExecute $remotehost $command`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152258/discussion-between-rashcuva-and-abis).